# Removing zero columns or rows using eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to remove columns or rows that are all zero elements. I am sure there is using the functions in the eigen library but I do not know how.

Right now I am doing it like so, with the idea of the while loop being used in case there are multiple rows/columns that sum to zero I dont want to exceed range limits or pass any zero rows.

```
void removeZeroRows() {
    int16_t index = 0;
    int16_t num_rows = rows();

    while (index < num_rows) {
        double sum = row(index).sum();
        // I use a better test if zero but use this for demonstration purposes 
        if (sum == 0.0) {
            removeRow(index);
        }
        else {
            index++;
        }

        num_rows = rows();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently (Eigen 3.3), there is no direct functionality for this (though it is planned for Eigen 3.4).

Meanwhile can use something like this (of course, `row` and `col` can be interchanged, and output is just for illustration):

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A;
A.setRandom(4,4);
A.col(2).setZero();

// find non-zero columns:
Eigen::Matrix<bool, 1, Eigen::Dynamic> non_zeros = A.cast<bool>().colwise().any();

std::cout << "A:\n" << A << "\nnon_zeros:\n" << non_zeros << "\n\n";

// allocate result matrix:
Eigen::MatrixXd res(A.rows(), non_zeros.count());

// fill result matrix:
Eigen::Index j=0;
for(Eigen::Index i=0; i<A.cols(); ++i)
{
    if(non_zeros(i))
        res.col(j++) = A.col(i);
}

std::cout << "res:\n" << res << "\n\n";
```

Generally, you should avoid resizing a matrix at every iteration, but resize it to the final size as soon as possible.

With Eigen 3.4 something similar to this will be possible (syntax is not final yet):

```
Eigen::MatrixXd res = A("", A.cast<bool>().colwise().any());
```

Which would be equivalent to Matlab/Octave:

```
res = A(:, any(A));
```

Comment: Is this Eigen 3.4 code available anywhere such that I can upgrade to a development branch to take advantage of this one line function?

Comment: How to check for non NAN instead of non zero?